# To connect boost library to RAD Studio XE7

Tags: c++, boost, crc

It is necessary to include library boost (is more exact, section crc) in RAD Studio XE7, without using GetIt Package Manager. The version boost 1_65_1 is already downloaded. Help, please.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you are having trouble with code please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Presumably this is asking how to add include/header search paths to RAD Studio. In which case, it would seem that simply reading the documentation would be easier than asking on SO, e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Include_Files => http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler_Directories_and_Conditionals

Comment: I have not found those lib-files. In the Internet wrote that in a command line it is necessary to enter a command 'bootstrap'. At me it gives out an error " 'cl' is not the internal or external command executed by the program or a package file." As it to solve?